# Fixed Price for child item of bundle product in magento

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am trying to create a bundle product with fixed price and give a discount to them.

Then add more items on this bundle while few item will have some extra charges (fixed price).

**For example: A bundle product fixed price is $500 and discount percent is 50%. 
Now, in bundle item I will add**

**1. Item 1 (fixed price: 0)**

**2. Item 2 (Fixed price: 100)**

This gives me a bundle item obviously of $250 (500- 500*50%). However, price of my dropdown item no. 2 will also have $50 ($100- 100*50%).
But, I want to have **$100** (fixed) of my dropdown item no. 2's price.

I have tried looking in to following file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php
```

I am not sure which file is the right one to achieve this..

Anyone knows the answer, please.

Comment: How did you apply the discount? Is it a price rule?

Comment: Hi Sander, No, it's not the price rule. Discount is simply applied on bundle product itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it will trigger a bug but I am getting the desired result by commenting out following line:

```
$price = $this->getLowestPrice($bundleProduct, $price, $bundleQty);
```

From following function in **app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php**

```
public function getSelectionFinalTotalPrice($bundleProduct, $selectionProduct, $bundleQty, $selectionQty,
                                            $multiplyQty = true, $takeTierPrice = true)
{
    if (is_null($selectionQty)) {
        $selectionQty = $selectionProduct->getSelectionQty();
    }

    if ($bundleProduct->getPriceType() == self::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) {
        $price = $selectionProduct->getFinalPrice($takeTierPrice ? $selectionQty : 1);
    } else {
        if ($selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceType()) { // percent
            $product = clone $bundleProduct;
            $product->setFinalPrice($this->getPrice($product));
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'catalog_product_get_final_price',
                array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $bundleQty)
            );
            $price = $product->getData('final_price') * ($selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceValue() / 100);

        } else { // fixed
            $price = $selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceValue();
        }
    }

    /*
     * commented bellow line to have fixed price as entered in backend 
     * for child item of bundle product.
     */
    //$price = $this->getLowestPrice($bundleProduct, $price, $bundleQty);

    if ($multiplyQty) {
        $price *= $selectionQty;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

I hope it will help others and also I will get notified if this change will trigger any bug.